# change Geom_smooth default legend color

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dplyr

I am using geom_smooth and it gives me default legend line color blue that I cannot use in the plot. Is there a way of changing the default color for geom_smooth legend line?

for example, I wand to change the legend colour to black for line type in the following plot

```
      library(reshape2)
    library(ggplot2)
d1<-melt(mtcars,id=c("mpg","cyl"))
        p<-ggplot(d1,aes(x=mpg,y=value,factor=variable,color=cyl))
        p1<-p+geom_smooth(aes(linetype = as.factor(cyl)),se = F,stat = "smooth",method = "glm",size=.5,  inherit.aes = T)+
          scale_linetype_manual("line type",labels = rp, values=c(1,5,4,3))
```

[image]

Comment: You have supplied no code. Why did not changing `color=` (outside or inside or `aes` not work)? What's wrong with `update_geom_defaults()` if you want it changed globally? There are manual pages for all the geoms that one shld read before asking for aid.

Comment: ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, col=am)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()

d1<-melt(mtcars,id=c("mpg","cyl"))
ggplot(data = d1,aes(x=mpg,y=value,factor=variable,color=cyl))+geom_smooth()+theme(legend.position="left")

Comment: if you can display legennd for this plot, it will be blue

Comment: please add reshape2 package

Comment: @user20650 kindly check updates

Comment: did you get any clue?

Comment: if you add `+ 
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes= list(color = "black")))` to your last plot does that get what you want?

Comment: wow done thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my comment, if you add an override to your legend you can change how the color displays. This should work:

```
p1<-p+geom_smooth(aes(linetype = as.factor(cyl)),se = F,stat = "smooth",method = "glm",size=.5,  inherit.aes = T)+
  scale_linetype_manual("line type",labels = c("100 yr", "50 yr", "25 yr"), values=c(1,5,4,3)) + 
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes= list(color = "black")))
```

And the resulting plot is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you add `+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes= list(color = "black")))` to your last plot do

This solves thanks @Mike