# How to include loess line in ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to enclose the green loess line in the legend. I tried with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44990518/6574038) but I don't know how to set the linetype to the loess line (the first `stat_smooth()`). How would I do that? It should appear just to the right of the existing legend as: **----- loess**.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color=as.factor(vs), group=as.factor(vs))) +
  stat_smooth(method="loess", se=FALSE, color="green", 
              lty=2, show.legend=TRUE,
              aes(group=as.factor(vs))) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE),
              se=FALSE, show.legend=TRUE)+
  theme_minimal()+
  # scale_linetype_manual("foo", values="green") +  # won't work
  # guides(linetype=guide_legend(override.aes=list(color="black"))) +  # won't work either
  guides(color = guide_legend(direction = "horizontal")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0, 1), 
        legend.justification = c("left", "top"),
        legend.box.just = "right")
```

[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. For example, you have 4 specifications for color: main function `color=as.factor(vs)`; first smooth `col="green"` and `color=as.factor(vs)`; second smooth `color=as.factor(vs)` . I would start by removing redundant code (color in main function should be fine).

Comment: @PoGibas Ok I reduced the code, thanks for the hint. By doing this I noticed when I remove `color="green` the loess smoothes have the same color as the related curves. So you suggest to seperate them? How would I do it then?

Comment: In your case I would use `aes(linetype = factor(vs))` in first smooth instead of ` lty=2`

Comment: @PoGibas No, this does not bring the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can introduce an empty factor and tune it to look like the loess plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs2 = factor(vs, levels = c("0", "1", "dotted")
                      , labels = c("0", "1", "dotted")))

ggplot(mtcars2, aes(wt, mpg, color=vs2, linetype=vs2)) +
stat_smooth(method="loess", se=FALSE, color="green", 
            lty=2, show.legend=TRUE,
            aes(group=vs2)) +
stat_smooth(method="lm", formula=y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE),
            se=FALSE, show.legend=TRUE)+
theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"), drop = FALSE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 1, 2), drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Discarding `guides(.)` and updating `theme(legend.direction = "horizontal")` from my original code this works exactly as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the `loess` smoother, *map* `color` and `linetype` to a string constant in `aes` to make it appear in the legend with an appropriate label. Change the line type in the resulting legend using `guides(..., override.aes(...)`

```
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = vs, group = vs, linetype = vs)) +
  stat_smooth(aes(color = "loess", linetype = "loess"), method = "loess", se = FALSE) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw= TRUE), se = FALSE, show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 1, 2)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1, 1, 2)))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]